# area of one rose petal using iterated integral but the outer integral is of radius

Tags: curves, polar-coordinates, iterated-integrals

I have a Rose leaf, described by the equation `r=a*sin(3θ)`, from θ=0 to $\frac{\pi}{6}$.
I need to make an iterated integral of this area.
It's easy when the outer integral is of θ ($\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \int_{0}^{asin(3\theta)} r dr d\theta$), but I struggled trying to swap this order. I can't determine the range of $\theta$ with fixed r.
So briefly I need boundaries {b, c} of $\int_{0}^{a} \int_{b}^{c} r d\theta dr$ for this one leaf

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Please provide additional context. Can you show the set up you came up with for the order $dr ~ d\theta$ and where are you getting stuck in using that to change the order?

Comment: @MathLover , edited.

Comment: ok in the order $d\theta ~ dr$, it will be $ \displaystyle \int_0^a \int_{(\arcsin (r/a))/3}^{\pi /3 - (\arcsin (r/a))/3} r ~d\theta ~dr$

Answer (score 1):

The answer is $\int_0^a \int_{(\arcsin (r/a))/3}^{\pi /3 - (\arcsin (r/a))/3} r ~d\theta ~dr$, thanks to Math Lover.